# Changes in data model of one realm requires migration of another realm. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have two realm databases in my app.

One is shipped with the app (read only for the user) and is located in NSBundle.MainBundle.
The other one is created (read and write for the user) and stored in the documents directory.

However, if I make a change to the model in the bundled realm, the user created realm is not working and says that migration is required.

How is this possible? These are two different realms located in different locations.

After some testing in a dummy project with 3 different realms (stored in same location, but with different names) I can see in the RealmBrowser that all the class names are included in the realm file. Why are they mixed? Shouldn't they be standalone databases?

And while we are one the topic:
What is the difference between creating multiple realm files vs creating ' realm file with multiple classes?

Thanks for any clarification!

Regards,

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Realm files will create "tables" in the backing file upon first access for all Realm models defined in your app binary. This makes the common case of using a single Realm extremely simple for end users. Even if you're using multiple Realms but you want them all to share the same set of models, this is quite simple and supported by this default behavior.

If you want to use multiple Realms each with different models, you can pass your models to the `objectTypes` property of your `Realm.Configuration`:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(objectTypes: [MyClass.self, MyOtherClass.self])
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

You can read more about this feature in the [Class Subsets](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#class-subsets) section of Realm's documentation.